# Chromium app icons doesn't show on launcher (Unity)

Tags: unity, chromium

When I configure a chromium app to open as a new window, it does so, but the chromium icon is displayed in the launcher instead of the app icon (in windows it shows the app icon in the tray).

This creates a launcher with many different chromium icons and it's hard to relate which app is in which icon. Does anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

I'm using Chromium 41.0.2272.76 and Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by adding the shortcut to your applications folder.

Here's how I do it via point and click.

Given that you've set the app the open in it's own window,

1. From the App launcher, or the `chrome://apps` page, right click the web app and select `Create shortcuts`.

[image]

2. From the pop-up, select `Desktop`.

   - This allows you to rename the shortcut.

[image]

3. Next, navigate to your `home` folder and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to view hidden files and folders.
4. Naviate to `.local` > `share` > `applications`.
5. Cut and Paste the app shortcut you created in step 2 into this folder.

Now anytime you click the app via the App launcher or the apps page, the web app will launch in it's own window, and icon of the web app will appear in the lanuncher (and in the application switcher when you use  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>). The other benefit if you are using the Unity desktop is you can launch the web app via Dash by just searching for the shortcut you created in step 2.